# Developing a new OS based on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, server

I want to make a new OS based on Ubuntu (for banks, and higher end businesses in the beginning... with home users and even a server version later on...) I am willing to hire qualified people to help, or possibly partner with someone. Essentially I want to make a hardened version of Linux, similar to Ubuntu. I can base it from Ubuntu or another flavor.

I haver some coding knowledge, but most recently have been in data science and cyber security. I also have a moderate amount of experience with Ubuntu and Ubuntu Server.

Thoughts? Recommendations? Where is a good place to begin?

Comment: If a Commercial Enterprise you need to contact Canonical Legal. http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy

Comment: @oldfred: That's only true if you wish to use brand and binaries. You don't have to ask any permission in order to use Ubuntu as a base for your commercial projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a kind of big question, but if you're serious about making a distro, I think it can't hurt if you get Linux From Scratch and follow that. It's a DIY distro in the form of a book that provides step by step instructions and you end up with a working distro. It's very useful to understand all the underlying concepts of a GNU+Linux distro.

It would probably be easier for you to sell your services to your customers and provide your resulting hardening to upstream Ubuntu. Certainly much cheaper for you as you won't need to maintain everything yourself.